# SENDING ARRAY as Email in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, phpmailer

I would like to send an array in a table as body of email.
Here is my code

```
        $mail->Subject = 'ORDER NOTICE';
        $mail->Body = '<p>
        Dear ' .$dn.',<br>
        An Order has been made on '. $date .'to be delivered to this address; '.$da.'<br>
        Please expect your order within 2 days.
        Please note that this order is Pay on delivery.<br>
        These are the Items to be delivered '.implode("<br>", $_SESSION["cart"]); 
        </p>';
```

The email sends but the array stored in the $_SESSION["cart"] is not displayed

Comment: Are you making sure that `$_SESSION["cart"]` is set?

Comment: Is `$_SESSION['cart']` an array of strings?

Comment: Check what is in it with `var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);`

Comment: No i am not making sure that $_SESSION["cart"] is set.

Comment: The session is an array of 1 string and 2 numbers

Comment: $_SESSION["cart"]= array('item_name', 'item_price','item_quantitiy')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely to me that what you actually want will involve parsing the content of the variable, and not just blindly dumping its contents, so i'll answer both.

### Displaying the array in the e-mail

The body of the e-mail is html, so this is really no different than displaying the array in the browser. You cannot simply echo its contents though (like with `implode`). You have to encode it as a text so that it doesn't corrupt the entire document/email; What if some string in that array contained the string 'but Baseball < Football !'. That `<` would be seen as the start of an HTML element, and break everything.

Luckily PHP has a build-in function for this, `var_export`; we can use that together with the `nl2br` function which adds `<br>`s on newlines.

So you could replace `implode("<br>", $_SESSION["cart"])` with `nl2br(var_export($_SESSION["cart"], true))`

### Cleaner method

What you more likely should do though, is just treat the html e-mail as another document (just like your `view my cart` page which your website likely has).

```
$html  = '';
$html .= sprintf('<p>Dear <em>%s</em>,',
                 htmlentities($dn)    );
$html .= sprintf('An Order has been made on <strong>%s</strong>',
                 htmlentities($date)  );
$html .= sprintf('<p>to be delivered to this address:</p>');
$html .= sprintf('<pre>%s</pre><br>',
                 htmlentities($da)    );
$html .= sprintf('<p>Please expect your order within <strong>%s</strong></p>',
                 '2 days'             );
$html .= sprintf('<p>Please note that this order is Pay on delivery.</p>');
$html .= sprintf('<p>These are the Items to be delivered:</p>');
$html .= sprintf('<ul>');
foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $line) {
    // Do something with each entry here (i dont know whats in there)
    $html .= sprintf('<li>%s x  %s</li>',  // maybe something like this:
                     '5x',                 // - amount
                     'Blue T-shirt'    );  // - description
}
$html .= sprintf('</ul>');
$html .= sprintf('<p>See you soon !</p>');

$mail->Subject = 'ORDER NOTICE';
$mail->Body    = $html;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Raxi, your answer was IT for me, It was the foreach part that was the missing link. I defintely rewrote the code in your suggested format and it proved to be the solution. thank you once again. I have never used "sprintf" so i learnt a new thing too.

Comment: cool cool, nice work